# Does FishEye work with TFS using a GIT repository?

Tags: git, tfs, atlassian-fisheye, atlassian-crucible

I'm interested in using Crucible/FishEye but it doesn't support TFS.

Has anyone tried Crucible/FishEye using a TFS GIT repository?  Does that work?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. We use it internally with TFS Git repositories.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen we are trying to do the same thing as you and I get unexplained errors. See this Jira Link: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CRUC-7291

Comment: We are now using the pull request functionality in TFS 2013 with Update 4 applied:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/06/10/git-pull-request-visual-studio-online.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it does. The documentation does not require the use of Stash so Crucible should work just fine with any Git repository.

TFS Git is just Git.

Comment: Does it support other protocols than http(s)? Can't find a valid source

Comment: @spankmaster79 no, it doesn't support key exchange